# Azure Function app stopping immediately on development machine

Tags: azure-functions

As soon as I run my solution one or more of my function apps immediately stop with the following output.

job host started
stopping host

Answer (score 0):

This is because there were HttpTriggers in all of the functions and they were trying to listen on the same port.

The solution is to right-click each function app in turn, select `Properties` from the menu, go to the `Debug` tab, and in the `Application arguments` add the following:

```
host start --port 7071
```

Ensuring the port number is unique in each case.

Comment: An easier solution is to edit local.settings.json and add Host object   "Host": {
    "LocalHttpPort": 9123
  }, https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=windows%2Ccsharp%2Cbash#local-settings-file

Comment: A note is that --port takes precedence